# Switch View Controllers in a Page View Controller Programmatically | Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `UIButton` (also created programmatically) in my `View Controller` that's in the `Page View Controller`.  I would like to switch to another `View Controller` in that same Page View Controller.  Here is what I have tried to use:

```
@objc func myOpinionAction(_ sender:UIButton!)
{
    PageViewController().setViewControllers([suggestionPage()], direction: UIPageViewController.NavigationDirection.forward, animated: true)
}
```

This plain out doesn't work (I am trying to switch to suggestionPage)  Another method I've tried is this:

```
PageViewController().transition(from: PageViewController().viewControllers![0], to: PageViewController().viewControllers![2], duration: 0.3, options: UIView.AnimationOptions.curveEaseInOut, animations: nil, completion: nil)
```

This gives me a **Thread 1: signal SIGABRT** error on my:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
```

First line of code in my `AppDelegate`, I'd assume it's due to an unwrapping of an option issue?
Does anyone know how I'm either using the functions wrong or have a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
func forward() {
        if currentPageIndex < totalPageIndex {
            pageController?.setViewControllers([viewControllerAtIndex(index: currentPageIndex + 1)], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    func backward() {
        if currentPageIndex > 0 {
            pageController?.setViewControllers([viewControllerAtIndex(index: currentPageIndex - 1)], direction: .reverse, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code as given below. When you are writing `PageViewController()` it means you are creating new object and of type `PageViewController` and you are trying to set page on that object instance, which is not added to your view.

```
@objc func myOpinionAction(_ sender:UIButton!)
{
    pageViewController.setViewControllers([suggestionPage()], direction: UIPageViewController.NavigationDirection.forward, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: I get "Instance member 'setViewControllers' cannot be used on type 'pageViewController'; did you mean to use a value of this type instead?" back with that option

Comment: If I try "PageViewController?.setViewControllers...." i get "Type 'PageViewController?' has no member 'setViewControllers'"

Comment: Your pageViewController is should be of type UIPageViewController.

Comment: It is a UIPageViewController